# ERROR: ISO C++ forbids initialization in array new

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, dev-c++

Following is my code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
int *x= new int[10] (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);//error observed here
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    cout<<x[i];
}
delete[] x;
getch();
return 0;
}
```

I am getting the ISO C plus plus  forbids initialization in array new error 
Please let me know the source of this error. thanks

Comment: If you know the contents of the array, initialize it on the stack with `int x[] = { 0, ... };`, optionally with `static`...

Comment: When you start using the newer compiler, skip using `new` and use `std::vector` instead, like: `std::vector<int> x{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};`. This lets you skip using `delete` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ for [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Uniform_initialization) you have to use bracers:

```
int *x= new int[10] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Comment: Now it says: expected `,' or `;' before '{' token for the same line.

Comment: It works fine on ideone. Yes, I guess its time to get a new compiler. Thanks

Comment: @user2492461 the compiler in dev c++ probably doesn't support C++11

Comment: @user2492461 The default compiler that comes with Dev-C++ is supposedly very old and outdated. You can install a new compiler and use the environment with that instead. The important part is to add the `-std=c++11` flag to the compiler, to enable uniform initialization (as it's a feature new in the C++11 standard).

Answer (score 0):

Your use of parentheses when constructing x implies passing arguments to the array constructor.  Use braces instead to supply initializers for the array values.